# Django get related foreignkey count (Distinct)

Tags: django, django-models

i want to get count of related foreignkey values like this;

Assume that, the value table of this

```
GAME        STATUS
GAME1         FINAL
GAME2         FINAL
GAME3         PLAYOFF
GAME4         FINAL
```

I want to show how many different situations (the result from the table above should be 2)

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
    gamestatus = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Status(models.Model):
    name...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this using [**`distinct`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
Game.objects.values('gamestatus').distinct().count()
```

Comment: I solved using this:  Status.objects.filter(...).annotate(Count('name', distinct=True)).count()

Comment: your solution would work, but it will generate a query like this:
`SELECT game__status.game_id, COUNT(DISTINCT app_status.game_id) AS game__count FROM app_status GROUP BY app_status.game_id ORDER BY NULL`, Where mine will only generate `SELECT DISTINCT 'app_status'.'game_id' FROM 'app_status'`

Comment: how can i filter ?I'm using this code for matches **matches=Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament)** and full code of count **statuscount=Status.objects.filter(game__in=matches).annotate(Count('name',distinct=True)).count()**

Comment: `Status.objects.filter(game__tournament=tournament).values('name').distinct().count()`

Comment: thank you for suggestion i replaced with `statuscount=Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament).values('gamestatus').distinct().count()`

Answer (score 0):

Try [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) annotation:

```
from from django.db.models import F

Game.objects.annotate(status=F("status__name"))
```

Comment: I solved using this:  Status.objects.filter(...).annotate(Count('name', distinct=True)).count()